# Why some part of code is not participate in execution process

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to split network into two groups (g1 and g2) according to the degree of nodes (if degree of node d>=691 then node is add in g1 otherwise node is add in g2)

```
import networkx as nx
import random
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
from networkx.algorithms.assortativity.mixing import degree_mixing_matrix # \attribute_mixing_matrix, numeric_mixing_matrix
from networkx.algorithms.assortativity.pairs import node_degree_xy #, \node_attribute_xy

from operator import itemgetter
from networkx.exception import NetworkXError
import networkx.convert as convert

g = nx.read_edgelist('/home/suman/Desktop/dataset/Email-Enron.txt',create_using=None,nodetype=int,edgetype=int)

s=sorted(g.degree_iter(),key= itemgetter(1),reverse=True)



perc=1
def modify_nw_random(g,perc):

while(perc<=100):
    ntm = round((float(perc)/100)*len(g))
    #print ntm    
    while(ntm != 0):
        v = random.randrange(1,len(g))
        print"node:", v
        d=g.degree(v)
        print"degree:", d

        g1=nx.Graph()
        g2=nx.Graph()

        if g.has_node(v) and (d>=691):

                g1.add_node(v)

        else:
               g2.add_node(v)

        g.remove_node(v)     
        ntm = ntm-1
        if(ntm<=0):break

    perc=perc+1
    print "perc:",perc
    if(perc>100):break

    N1=nx.number_of_nodes(g1)
    print N1
    r2=nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(g1)
    print ("%f"%r2)        

    N2=nx.number_of_nodes(g2)
    print N2
    r3=nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(g2)
    print ("%f"%r3)                 

 modify_nw_random(g,perc)
```

here first loop are executed when perc = 1 and then  perc is increase by 1 (perc=perc+1) this is not execute .it means following part of code is not participating in execution process

```
perc=perc+1
    print "perc:",perc
    if(perc>100):break

    print "node in g1:", g1.nodes()
print "node in g2:", g2.nodes()
    N1=nx.number_of_nodes(g1)
    print N1
    r2=nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(g1)
    print ("%f"%r2)        

    N2=nx.number_of_nodes(g2)
    print N2
    r3=nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(g2)
    print ("%f"%r3)
```

can any one help me that, for solving my mistakes in this code

Comment: What's the behavior you see? What I can see is that the instruction `ntm = ntm-1` is not correctly indented so your `while(ntm != 0)` loop will never end...

Comment: sorry i edit the code and this is the my code  ,please see and trying to solve my problem

Comment: What is the error you see? Did you try to print the `ntm` variable value? This could give you an indication of where the software stops...